# Combobox in visualbasic.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to ask how I can add an item to the combo box list.

Now, the scenario is like this: I allow users to add new work through a `button` and once this `button` is pressed, input box will be shown, prompting the user to enter new worker's name, however I am not sure how to update the items in `comboBox` list with the new name.

The `comboBox` list will contain all the workers.

This is what I have done:

```
Dim new_worker As String

  new_worker = Input Box("Enter the new worker's name :")
```

Thanks if u can help me!

Comment: Perhaps you should edit this to include that you wanted to include contents in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Her is the code

Xml(filename is Sample):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dataset>
   <table></table>
</dataset>
```

Button_click:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim str As String = InputBox("enter the name")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.ReadXml("C:\Documents and Settings\tech1.TECH01\My Documents\simple\simple\Sample.xml")
    i = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    If str <> "" Then
        ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add("col" & i)
        Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).NewRow
        dr("col" & i) = str
        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr)
        ds.WriteXml("C:\Documents and Settings\tech1.TECH01\My Documents\simple\simple\Sample.xml", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
    End If
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("col" & i).ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Form_load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim i As Integer
    ds.ReadXml("C:\Documents and Settings\tech1.TECH01\My Documents\simple\simple\Sample.xml") 'your xml file's path
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("col" & i).ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, inputbox should never be used, its just plain silly.

Secondly, to add text to a combobox

```
combobox1.items.add("an item text")
```

Comment: Why should it never be used? I've never used one before but now you've got me curious as to why I shouldn't.

Comment: @thehealingprocess its not a matter of function its a matter of control and response. The inputbox returns "" if the user presses cancel, what happens if the user presses OK with ""? the same thing as cancel which is bad, then there is of course the fact you cant style them or have any real control like where it shows or how

Comment: Fair enough. But can't you control button behavior with dialogresult?

Answer (score 0):

To insert an item in the combobox, simply use it's add function.

```
Combobox.items.add("The string of which you want to add")
```

If you want to use inputboxes:

Dim responseFromUser as String = Inputbox("Please Enter an item", "This is the title of the inputbox")

```
If responseFromUser <> "" then
 Combobox.items.add(responseFromUser)
End If
```

Comment: however, this code can only be used during run-time. The next time i run, the name is not in the list anymore, how to store in the list permanently?

Comment: What you want is to store the user's input in a database of your choosing, which wasn't specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code

```
  combobox1.Items.Add(new_worker)
```

or

```
  combobox1.Items.Add(InputBox("enter  your string"))
```

Comment: however, this code can only be used during run-time. The next time i run, the name is not in the list anymore, how to store in the list permanently?

Comment: then store in a sql table and upload the combo on page load

Comment: sorry im nt sure what is sql table...im using visual basic.net,i want to add this name to my combo box list,is it using array or something like that?

Comment: havent you used SQL Server

Comment: nope,i didnt use that before for vb. Erm can you teach me something like adding the new name to the combo box so that it will allow user to choose the new name? don use sql, just do inside vb

Comment: strings and array can store the values only on runtime. but database can store the values for permanent.

Comment: im thinking of typing code inside combo box : Private Sub cmbcollectedby_SelectedIndexChanged    ,using array but nt sure how.Erm, you know right if i don type code for this, i can str8 away go to the properties and type the current worker names in the combo box for the user to choose.However, there may be occasion where new worker arrives,thats y im thinking how to make changes to the list in the properties of the combo box. What i want to do is to add new name to the list so that it will be shown every it is run.

Comment: i understood. but if u gave code inside the "Private Sub cmbcollectedby_SelectedIndexChanged" it is only available for already added values not for new items. sql is not a difficult one. u can learn it very simple. if u know ms-access then use it also

Comment: actually my project in vb nw is linked to access also, can u explain to me how to add value in the new worker's field? thanks, u code u wrote i don seem to understand...so sorry

Comment: do u need access code? or?

Comment: there is one more way of using xml file. wait for a while. let get u the code

Comment: erm whichever method is easier and simple to understand,bcuz i run of time nw...thanks , my purpose is allow user to enter new worker's name so that the combo box in visual basic will allow them to choose the worker

Comment: so could you get the code?thanks

Comment: yeah i am now on that...wait for a moment

Comment: sure, sorry for rushing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sub btn_click()
    Dim str As String = InputBox("enter the name")
    Dim com as new SqlCommand("insert into tbl values('" & str & "')",conn)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    com=New SqlCommand("Select name from tbl",conn)
    Dim da as new SqlDataAdapter(com)
    Dim ds as New Dataset
    da.Fill(ds)
    Combobox1.datasource=ds.Tables(0)
    Combobox1.DisplayMember="name"
    Combobox1.ValueMember="name"
 End Sub
 Sub Form1_Load()
    Dim com as SqlCommand=New SqlCommand("Select name from tbl",conn)
    Dim da as new SqlDataAdapter(com)
    Dim ds as New Dataset
    da.Fill(ds)
    Combobox1.datasource=ds.Tables(0)
    Combobox1.DisplayMember="name"
    Combobox1.ValueMember="name"
End Sub
```

Comment: you can also use this as solution. flag it as solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim name As String = InputBox("Enter a name")

    ComboBox1.Items.Add(name)
    ComboBox1.Sorted = True

End Sub
```

Sorted property in case you want it be alphabetically sorted